# uma calculadora em php

Tags: php, html

eu preciso de um código em PHP de uma calculadora, que some 4 notas e divida por 4 e se a media final for maior ou igual a 6 que ele mostre aprovado, senão reprovado. SCRR

```
<?php

       $nt1 = $_GET[$nt1];
       $nt2 = $_GET[$nt2];
       $nt3 = $_GET[$nt3];
       $nt4 = $_GET[$nt4];
       $mf = ( $nt1 + $nt2 + $nt3 + $nt4)/4;
       echo " $nt1, $nt2, $nt3, $nt4,  $mf ";

      if ( $mf >= 6  ) {
       echo "aprovado" ;

      }
      else{
       echo "Reprovado";

        } 
    ?>
```

Código em HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title> calculadora </title>
 </head>
  <body>
  <form action="calculadora.php" method = "get">
  <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Primeiro bimestre</td>
            <td><input name="$nt1" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Segundo bimestre</td>
            <td><input name="$nt2" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>terceiro bimestre</td>
            <td><input name="$nt3" type="text" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>quarto bimestre</td>
            <td><input name="$nt4" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input name="bt_validar" type="submit" value="Calcular" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código HTML do seu formulário aqui?

Comment: posso sim, mais aq nos comentários não cabe

Comment: vou editar a pergunta e postar lá pode ser??

Comment: Elabore melhor a sua pergunta Cristina. O StackOverflow não funciona assim: "Quero código X pra ontem porque tenho um prazo." Qual parte do código você não entendeu? Qual é a sua pergunta exatamente? Onde está o código em HTML correspondente?

Comment: vc não consegue fazer o calculo? acho melhor trocar os `name`s dos inputs, tire aquele cifração.

Comment: É pq no código em PHP, ele devia mostrar o resultado das somas qnd fizesse a divisão e se fosse maior ou igual a 6 era pra dar aprovado e se fosse menor era pra dar reprovado, só vai pra condição do else, independente do valor que dá. e não acho o erro

Comment: o código HTML coloquei na pergunta

Comment: rray, os names dos inputs são as variáveis que usei no PHP

Comment: Se está caindo só no else é suas variáveis devem estar como zero ou null olhe: `$nt1 = $_GET[$nt1];` assim vc diz para o php, quer o indice zero do `$_GET` só que ele não existe ...

Comment: Mais quero que o usuário dê o valor da variável entende? o que posso colocar no lugar? Pode me ajudar?

Comment: No php toda variávavel começa com `$` apenas tire ele do name dos inputs e dos `$nt1 = $_GET[$nt1];`, deixe apenas `$nt1 = $_GET['nt1'];`

Comment: Consegui, estava faltando aspas simples na variável. Obg rray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está pegando os dados do seu formulário de uma forma errada.

Ao invés de `$_GET[$nt1];` deveria ser `$_GET['nt1'];` e assim nos outros.

## [Veja o código em funcionamento aqui](http://solutionsagencia.com.br/calculadora).

Segue o código completo do exemplo baseado em seu código:

HTML:

```
<!-- não esqueça de abrir com tag <html>, inserir o <head> e fechar ele e tmabém de abrir <body> -->

<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="get" action="calcular.php">
Nota 1 <input id="nt1" name="nt1" type="text" /><br />
Nota 2 <input id="nt2" name="nt2" type="text" /><br />
Nota 3 <input id="nt3" name="nt3" type="text" /><br />
Nota 4 <input id="nt4" name="nt4" type="text" /><br />
<input id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" type="submit" value="Calcular" />
</form>

<!-- feche o <body> e feche o <html> -->
```

Arquivo PHP calcular.php:

```
<?php

    $nt1 = $_GET['nt1'];
    $nt2 = $_GET['nt2'];
    $nt3 = $_GET['nt3'];
    $nt4 = $_GET['nt4'];
    $mf = ( $nt1 + $nt2 + $nt3 + $nt4)/4;
    //echo " $nt1, $nt2, $nt3, $nt4,  $mf "; Esta linha vai imprimir as notas e e também a média

    if ( $mf >= 6  ) {
        echo "aprovado" ;
    }
    else{
        echo "Reprovado";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Era a falta de Aspa simples mesmo. Muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuito Obrigaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Isso, use também o `name` no seu `html` sem o `$`. E da mesma forma chame ele com as aspas e sem o `$` dentro de `$_GET[];`

Answer (score 2):

Quando você coloca `$nt4 = $_GET[$nt4];`

Ele entende o `$nt4` como uma variável do `PHP`, já que para declará-las você utiliza `$`, mesmo que você coloque entre `""` não da certo, e só substituir por `"nt4"`, não esquece de mudar no `html` tambem.